# Наложение элемента на другой

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть header, есть menu. В header есть лого. Нужно чтобы меню чуть-чуть заходило на лого, но с помощью

> margin-top:-30px;

не получается сделать, они отталкиваются друг от друга. Как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [position: absolute](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position);